# How to test function in a react SFC which using hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-test-components-that-use-hooks

the document show that we should use React DOM to test component.But in many cases, our logical components render another ui component.And maybe the function in logical component will be passed to the ui component as a prop, just like

```
function Foo(){
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  });
  function onChange(value) {
    setCount(value);
  }
  return <Bar value={count} onChange={onChange} />
}

function Bar(props){
  const { value, onChange }  = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {value} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => onChange(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this case, how can I test the `onChange()` and other functions which can't be obtained in DOM?This is the simplest case. If we use some component library like material-design and ant-design, we usually don't know the DOM structure.

Comment: In this case, u simply add an id to `p` tag .. but i don't know if u use material-ui

Answer (score 0):

As the docs suggest:

> If your testing solution doesn’t rely on React internals, testing
>   components with Hooks shouldn’t be different from how you normally
>   test components.

The goal is not to test the `onChange` function at all, whether the hooks work or not is already tested by the React team.

Your current change to render a component does not change the test at all, rendering `Foo` still renders a `button` and `p` however deep the component chain goes.

On using a framework like `Antd` or `Material Design`, it might be difficult to know the complete DOM structure. But instead, or better you can query by things that the user sees on your page.

For eg. using the [React testing library](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library) recommended in the docs:

```
const button = getByText(container, /Click Me/i);
```

This ties in directly with what user is seeing on the page and leads to much better tests.

Comment: Sometimes a function will call other functions with some params.In the components 
 which extends React.Component, I could expect whether component's other function have been called with designated params.So that when I was refactoring my component, I could make sure if the component is working as well as before.But now, I can only know the DOM's change?Test is not only with UI but also with logic.

Comment: yes, testing the implementation details is a [recipe for brittle tests](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/testing-implementation-details), changing the params, state names does not result in changes for your user, it just leads more test refractoring. Instead test what the user is directly interacting with

Comment: for example, the `Table` component of `antd` could accept `pagination` and `onChange()` props to render a pagination under table and call `onChange` when change page number.If my component render Table, how could I call the function which defined inner my component and pass to Table?Maybe after some versions, the DOM structure has some changes so that I can't find the target element to emit its `onClick` like before.

Comment: The easiest way is to ask yourself _how would the user do that?_, user would click on a button/link with number on it, then wait till it shows a page with that number as active

Comment: on change in DOM structure after versions, like I mentioned you could fetch by text that the button has, that way you don't have to know the DOM structure. This is important because that's what the user sees

Comment: In this way, the `shallow` render of `react-test-renderer` and `enzyme` is useless?I usually use this api to test my class component

Comment: yes, always render the whole component. Check out react testing library as suggested in the docs